# wurtzite unit cell of ZnO

Tags: crystallography, vesta

am looking to draw wurtzite unit cell of ZnO, and i find two of them
[image]

and the second one

[image]

how can I draw the first one in software like vesta?

Comment: I think above is orthogonal cell and bottom one is hexagonal cell. You can simply check material project , where you can get initial geometry

Comment: You can draw first one in ovito by transform hexagonal box to orthogonal box and slicing extra atom. You first have to find repeatable unit in orthogonal direction. Make sure not to take repeatable atoms in your unit cell

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @pranavkumar since the question changed and is now only about how to draw the first one, maybe you can turn that comment into an answer?

Comment: Correction to the previous comment, It is not an orthogonal cell , only difference between first and second is that origin lies at Zn atom.

Comment: They are the same, just shifted. Start from the rightmost Zn atom in the first cell, now follow the bonds, the O on top the, Zn in the tetrahedra, the O on top of the tetrahedra, and another Zn on the top-right corner. They make the exact structure of your second cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1 : find the coordinate of a $\ce{Zn}$ atom, for example,[image]

Atom: 1 Zn1 Zn 0.33333 0.66667 0.00055

step 2 : go to edit> unit cell and click on transform
[image]

Fill origin shift as 0.33333 0.6667 0.0055 and click ok and again ok
[image]
**BAZINGAA**
[image]